# Implementing Facebook Credits - App not responding (signed_request parsing error in callback imeplemntation)

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, json, encoding

*This is the continuation of the my [earlier post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9617943/what-is-wrong-in-facebook-credits-implementation/9619223#9619223)*

Since yesterday I have been trying to implement the **facebook credits** following the official tutorials. May be my noobness or the inadequate information I faced lot of problem which I have resolved one by one and I have arrived to the final step (hopefully)

I guess there is something to do with **order_info** which I am not sure

I have created a basic page based on the tutorial given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/build/). This page has a simple button. Upon clicking on it calls the placeOrder() function which is almost copy paste code given in the tutorial.

Now, I get this error message

[image]

The callback.php is also implemented and seems like FB has pinged the callback.php. But the problem seems to be that the signed_request is not as expected.

I got this error message from the apache log

> [Fri Mar 09 11:17:20 2012] [error] [client 66.220.146.244] Unknown
>   algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 *but got data dump*:

Note: (but got data dump are the extra debug variables which I have added to find what is coming the $data['algorithm'] and $data entirely

I have implemented code to **dump the signed_request variable in the db** for further debugging and from debugging I have debugged and traced

Here is the complete code of callback.php

```
<?php

//based on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/callback/


include_once 'Config.php';

mysql_connect('myhost','usr','zzz');
mysql_select_db("mydb");

//dump the request into the db
$request = join(':', $_REQUEST);
$request = mysql_real_escape_string($request);
$query = "insert into fbcredits_callback(data)values('$request')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$fb_signed_req = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];

echo parse_signed_request($signed_request, Config::$appSecret);

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
   error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 but got '.$data['algorithm'].'data dump:'.join(':',$data));
   return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

?>
```

The above error message is generated at this line

```
  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
   error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 but got '.$data['algorithm'].'data dump:'.join(':',$data));
   return null;
  }
```

Update: I debugged the output step by step, at below step $data returns null

```
 $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
```

Which means the decoding is not happening properly. Can some one tell me what is going wrong here?

Complete code of buy.php

```
<?php 
include_once 'Config.php';
include_once 'fb-sdk/facebook.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Credits Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '<?php echo Config::$appId?>',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : false, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'http://199.192.xxx.yyy/buy.php', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });

var callback = function(data) {
    if (data['order_id']) {
        alert('called back');
      return true;
    } else {
      //handle errors here
      alert('some error');
      return false;
    }
  };

function placeOrder(){

    alert('in placeOrder()');

    var order_info = {
        item_code: "someItemCode",
        user_id: "1313213131"
    };
    alert('creating obj');

    var obj = {
            method: 'pay',
            order_info: order_info,
            action: 'buy_item',
            dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true},
         app_id: '<?php echo Config::$appId?>'
          };
     alert('calling ui');
     FB.ui(obj, callback);

}

</script>

<input type="button" value="post" onclick="postFeed()" />
<input type="button" value="Buy" onclick="placeOrder()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Additional info:

- My webserver has SSL support (installed test certificate from verizon)
- Sandbox mode enabled (tried disabling also)

Comment: Obvious question: you haven't used the wrong app secret in your callback.php's config have you?

Comment: I am pretty sure about it :), I used correct secret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have resolved it. I read the [callback documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/callback/) carefully once again and found what mistake I was doing.

I was just parsing the **signed_request** and sending back the parsed data but I am suppose to send back the **content**

That is not the end, there is more to do which is documented well there with complete example.

Comment: Be sure to come back to mark your own answer as accepted so it closes this question.  Thanks :)

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 4 hours" does it mean, I can't accept my own answer coz it passed 4hours?

Comment: Yeah, I think the default time to wait is 12 hours.